# Is there a way of automated banking for f2p in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

I know for p2p they have a beast of burden thing, is there something similar for f2p? Like an amulet or something?

Comment: I doubt such an item exists - I would imagine auto-banking is one of the many incentives to try and entice people to pay for the game... classic trade-off of spending your time vs spending your money.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Beast of Burden are for carrying extra items - a way of expanding ones inventory essentially through the summoning skill.  It does not automatically bank your items for you.

Comment: @TimmyJim Dont forget about the yak! Its scroll move banks things. Sure, its not automatic, but thats more than likely what the OP was referring to Id say.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to automated banking for f2p players is magic notepaper which can note items in your inventory and legendary pets from Solomon's store which can bank items every 10 minutes. These do not automatically bank items.

Beast of burdens also do not automate banking. The main p2p thing that automatically banks items are sign of the porters.